# javascript to refresh part of an html page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

New to HTML and javascript. I'm trying to update a number that changes in another program without having to refresh the entire webpage using javascript. My home html page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="value.htm">Counter</a>
        <div id="counter"><h2>0</h2></div>
        <button>Update</button>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("#counter").load("value.html #count");
            })
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

When I press the button, nothing changes. value.html contains:

```
<div id="count">:="DB1".counter:</div>
```

which is just an int value that counts up every second. If I load up this page, it shows the correct int value. But for some reason, the id="counter" never updates on the main html page. I've tried on chrome and internet explorer with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That counter counts up because when you visit `value.html` you have a piece of script running in the browser. Loading `value.html` via `$.load()` will only load the raw HTML in that file, it will not run the scripts. Wait. Is that really all you have in that other file? How on earth is this counting up?

Comment: I'm running a Siemens program that counts up an int via a timer and counter. The html file accesses that value from the PLC. All in all, it's just an external int value that changes every second.

Comment: You're getting the old value from cache. Use a cache-buster in the Javascript.

Comment: @SteveBabs Ok, so when you visit `value.html` directly, the value doesn't really count up live inside the browser, correct? Instead, you'll see the value of the counter at the time when you load the page, right? If that's the case, try `load("value.html")`

Comment: I have added $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); within the ready function. It still doesn't work. Is that what you were referring to? Like I said, I'm new to this.

Comment: Exactly that, Chris. I'll give that a shot. Update, nothing is different. It still doesn't change when I push the button.

Comment: Did you try `load("value.html")`? Also, did you check the browser console for errors? Another thing you can try is `load("value.html?" + Math.random())`

Comment: IE is giving me an error that says "Object doesn't support this property or method" "jquery-3.2.1" That is probably the main issue. Did I not include it properly? I downloaded that js file and put it in a "Scripts" folder.

Comment: Should it be **#counter** instead of **#count** in your **.load** function?

Comment: @alfredo My variables are somewhat confusing there. Sorry. To my #counter is the div id on my main page and #count is the div id on my value.html page. Unless I understand it wrong, the value before ".load" is the id value you want to change on the current page and everything after ".load" is from the file I want to read from, right?

Comment: @ChrisG the error i mentioned above says it's on line 3 which is my <!DOCTYPE html> line.

Comment: @SteveBabs Yes, you are correct. Sorry for my confusion. I thought you were trying to load that same page. I tried your code locally by creating a dummy value.html page and it works fine so your code shown should work. Try these things to eliminate some possible problems:
1. Replace your jquery script line with this one `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> `
2. If that didn't work, then hard code a value in your value.html file and see if that still doesn't work.

Comment: @alfredo I actually have done both of those things. I've been picking at this for hours. At one point my value.html file only contained "58". I even tried making it read from a txt file. I don't know what the deal is. The error that I mentioned above is gone now though. No more errors, just not updating that 0.

Comment: @alfredo `<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
   $("button").click(function(){
    $("#counter").load("value.html");
   })
  });
 </script>` does this script work for you?

Comment: @SteveBabs Sorry, that worked for me!

Comment: @SteveBabs Did you test this in a proper browser, as in, not IE? What do you get in the Chrome's / Firefox's console?

Comment: @SteveBabs One more thing. Is the value.html page in the same folder as the main page?

Comment: @alfredo Yes its in the same folder.

Comment: @ChrisG Chrome is giving me some errors with the jquery thing. It is just seeming like I cant pull a value from another page. I'm going to be working on it a little more tomorrow. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Comment: Which errors...? Everything *should* work, so knowing the errors will help a great deal.

Comment: @ChrisG So with everything I have in the original post, excluding the `type="text/javascript"` in lines 6 and 13 and "#count" in line 16, I have no errors in Chrome and it words fine. In IE, I get "Object doesn't support this property or method jquery-3.2.1.min.js" and "Object expected index.html" at the `$(document).ready` line

Comment: @SteveBabs So the code works in Chrome as shown here, but it doesn't work in IE11. Is that correct?

Comment: @alfredo This is embarrassing but I'm using an older VM and it has IE8 on it. I expect you to come back and say "Well there's your problem".

Comment: @SteveBabs Exactly, jQuery 3.x doesn't support older IE versions.

Comment: @ChrisG Jeez. I was not aware. Thank you all so much!

Comment: @SteveBabs Retested it and it works in Firefox, Chrome, IE11, and Edge. I needed to run the code in a web server for Chrome, IE11, and Edge to work. Otherwise, Chrome would give me a cross origin error and IE just wouldn't work and would not give any errors.

Comment: @alfredo Which explains why it works in my VM and doesn't in my normal machine. It's running on a webserver on my VM.